# Memory size exhausted while trying to use MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using MysqliDb Class from there.

https://github.com/ajillion/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class/blob/master/MysqliDb.php

When i used on local pc, i don't have any problem. But I bought host yesterday. And I uploaded my files about 5 min ago and doesn't work. I checked my host and created error_log file and this..

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 75497472 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4294967296 bytes) in /home/(..)/MysqliDb.php on line 417
```

What is this problem?

I used this code on my config file. But same didn't work.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '192M');
```

Comment: Why is `call_user_func_array` mentioned? Do you have any data pointing to it? If you do, why don't you include it in the question?

Comment: He related the title to the code he linked. However, it may be an earlier error. I don't support the title (actually not well written)

Comment: memory usage obviously is the problem, so your attempted solution with `ini_set` is a valid answer. Have you tried with any larger figures -- say 300M? Having said that, it's likely that there's something wrong with the code for it to need that much memory; perhaps you could post the code where it crashes so we can see what it's doing?

Comment: I am using php version 5.3.21 and memory_limit 72M. I tired 500M and same :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that is that you are using LongText in your database.

Please read this message: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51386

So try to [mysqli::store_result](http://php.net/manual/mysqli.store-result.php) before bind_result.

Comment: Yes i used LongText. Where can i use this code on class and how? May you help me? I looked store_result but they are using with ->query.

Comment: I changed for mediumtext and fixed.

Answer (score -1):

`ini_set` commands that affect the limits of the server tend to be blocked (so, you may only be able to use the ones related to showing errors or so).

Bear in mind that you are trying to allocate 4.2 Gb, which is a fairly big amount of information for a website.

### Recommendations:

- Check if you are creating an infinite loop which tries to load that big bunch of information (not only in that class, but prior to that call in your own code).
- Use a lighter `mysqli` class (did you try [the one that comes by default with PHP 5](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php))?
- Check if your problem can be solved in another (maybe asynchronous? that amount of memory is insane for a website), lighter way, probably with another language like C or C++ to release the load out of Apache.
- Talk to your hosting provider and try to convince them to let you load 4.2 Gb of data.

Comment: so, somebody -1ed my answer, but didn't offer a "solution" to undownvote? Not really collaborative, actually