# Changing from varchar to mediumtext causes performance degradation

Tags: mysql, pdo, query-performance

I have a table which stores product reviews for a website.  The table uses varchar(1000) to store the review comment average response time is 0.5 seconds.  I changed the datatype of the column that holds data to mediumtext and the page response time jumps to 1.5 - 2 seconds. Baring in mind no additional data was added to the column and the PHP code is the same.

I don't think the query time is the issue, as MySQL reports it takes 0.019secs, which is the same whether varchar or mediumtext.

I'm at a loss to understand what's happened here.  I'm using MySQL PDO and PHP.  I don't know if it's a server issue, an inherent issue with mediumtext, or something else entirely.

I tried changing the table type from MyISAM to InnoDB but it made no difference.

Here is the PHP code:

```
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$attrs = array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $attrs);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE comment
       FROM reviews_product_comments
       WHERE part_id =:partid
         and language =:language");

foreach ($parts as $part) {

    // bind the parameters
    $stmt->bindValue(":partid", $part);
    $stmt->bindValue(":language", "en");

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        if ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {                
            $comment = $row['comment'];
            echo $comment . "<br>";        
        }
    }

}

$pdo = null;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: So you have *to profile* your code to make yourself know which part is to blame

Comment: I use the same PHP code in each test case.  When accessing the table with varchar response time is 0.5 seconds, when using mediumtext it jumps to 1.5 seconds +.  The code is identical, the only difference is the datatype.  So I don't think the code is the problem.  Also, MySQL query time in both cases reports to be ~0.015s.

Comment: under "mysql" you surely mean "I run this query in phpmyadmin", right?

Comment: How many reviews are we talking about? Few hundred or few hundred thousand?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'm using Navicat which has profile and status displayed for every query. Definitely no issue with indexes or query.  The query is very simple:

SELECT comment FROM reviews_product_comments WHERE part_id = ? and language = ?;

The part_id and language columns are indexed.

Comment: @SalmanA There's 23,000 records, so nothing substantial.  By definition of varchar(1000) no review comment can exceed 1000 characters, so it's not even transferring huge amounts of data.

Comment: at least run both with SQL_NO_CACHE for starter. And then profile **your code** as it's the only way to get the answer. There are no shamans happen t be around to tell you the reason from a crystal ball.

Comment: @YourCommonSense   I appreciate your help, but no need to be hostile, we're all here to learn aren't we?  I'm asking if anyone is aware of any known performance-related issue when using mediumtext instead of varchar, because all things being equal, that is the only thing that's changed.  I've updated my OP with the PHP code.

Comment: @BigMeaty I had similar problem with 10k rows of `mediumtext` data inside **MyISAM** table. I did not find a conclusive answer. I ended up moving text columns into a separate table and join when necessary. It worked.

Comment: @SalmanA  I've read of slow queries where mediumtext is used, but that doesn't seem to be my issue.  My issue seems to be the PHP/PDO connection.  My hunch is that MySQL PDO with mediumtext fields is causing extra overhead due to PHP PDO classing mediumtext as a 'large object', which isn't the case with varchar. I'll report back if I find something.

Comment: Only tag your question with PDO, if you're able to provide a [**Complete** and **Verifiable** example](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mcve) that is using PDO. Posting just a random piece of code doesn't qualify your question to use the tag.

Comment: @YourCommonSense  will you please stop removing my PDO tag from my post?  This issue seems to be related to PHP PDO classing the mediumtext column as a 'large object', which requires additional memory. I haven't posted 'random code', it's PHP code using MySQL PDO so that someone might see what the issue is. It is relevant to PDO so please stop removing it. You also marked it down?  How childish.

Comment: I would rather remove it, but mods will likely take your side, even despite the fact you have no idea what extension you're actually using and lack of MCVE.

Comment: @YourCommonSense You were correct, I'd posted the MySQLi code when I was testing that to see there was a difference.  Now updated with PDO example.  I've seen *plenty* of threads on here with far worse code samples. You seem to have a real chip on your shoulder / superiority complex.  Not sure why.  Either add something constructive, or I kindly ask you to 'do one'.

Comment: @SalmanA Excellent find on the duplicate question!  I added $stmt->store_result();  to the MySQLi example and it worked!  At least 'someone' was genuinely willing to help.  No amount of tracing would ever have identified that would be the required fix, so thank you.

Comment: @BigMeaty actually it was the other guy.

Comment: @YourCommonSense  thank you for your help finding the solution. See, there was no need to be so hostile or any reason to put me down was there? Just as I suspected, the solution was some little tweak that was needed to get it working with mediumtext.  There was no need to be so offensive, bordering on aggressive toward me, I asked a perfectly valid question and scolded me, and marked the question down.  No need for it. As I said before, we're all here to learn something.

Comment: DUP??  [_That  one_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763588/memory-size-exhausted-while-trying-to-use-mysqli) is about `mysqli` and `LONGTEXT`.  This one is about `PDO` and `MEDIUMTEXT`.  Voting to re-open.

Comment: @SalmanA - InnoDB effectively does what you did with an extra "parallel" table in MyISAM.

Comment: @rick care to check the edit history?

Answer (score -1):

The two datatypes are handled virtually identically.  There are many other possible reasons for sluggishness.  (But none that I know of that would say `MEDIUMTEXT` is worse than `VARHAR`.)

So...  Let's see if we can speed up the web page...

Put `microtime(true)` around the mysql calls -- to make sure it is MySQL, not PHP.  "0.019secs" makes sense; "1.5 - 2 seconds" sounds like something is going on in PHP.

Use InnoDB, *not* MyISAM.  (In spite of your claims to the contrary.)

Tune correctly; let's see `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%';`  How much RAM do you have?  (Swapping is terrible for performance.)

How many rows are you returning?  It's not practical to have more than a few dozen on a web page, so add `ORDER BY...LIMIT...`.

If the UI limit is 1000 characters, use `TEXT` or `VARCHAR(1000)`, not `MEDIUMTEXT`.  If you are trying to raise up to 64K bytes (*potentially* 4K utf8mb4 *characters*), then use `TEXT`.

You do need this (with the columns in either order):

```
INDEX(part_id, language)
```

If there has been a lot of "churn" (deletes and/or updates followed by more inserts) in the MyISAM table, the data can be fragmented, hence slow.  This can happen for both `VARCHAR` and `TEXT`.  This does not happen with InnoDB.